# How to use Proguard files?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I try to remove all Log's methods calls from code using custom proguard file for a release build. So I write my custom proguard file (took from net):

**`proguard-rules-release.txt`**

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

Added it in `build.grade`:

```
android {

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.txt', 'proguard-rules-release.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

But when I read `*.class` files in Android Studio by decompiler in `~/app/build/intermediates/classes/release` I find that it contains all calls as well as without proguard file.

What am I doing wrong?

**ADDED**
I decompiled apk-file even. Now, I'm sure that my proguard file doesn't work.
I rewrote `build.gradle` so:

```
release {
            minifyEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

And generated signed apk-file after decompiled it... But it all same has log outputs. I understand nothing...

Answer (score 1):

I found that I do wrong. Imma noobie. The answer was in my post...

```
minifyEnabled false
```

This option enables|disables support of proguard files.

Maybe someone will have a same problem.